# White screen in order view at magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, patches, ce-1.9.2.4

I already read alot of articles here but no one helped me.
Many orders is showing white screen.

> my php is 5.5.35 magento version 1.9.2.4(clean)

I already check:

```
max_execution_time
memory_limit
```

setted(htaccess)

```
#Magento Developer Mode
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

and (index.php)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

There is no error at exception or system logs

```
var/log/system.log
var/log/exception.log
```

I already put old files at adminhtml but nothing happens...

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/
```

solved patch SUPEE-7405:

```
Change line 124 in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php from $links = []; to $links = array();
```

**what else I could try?**

---

I found my problem. It´s this foreach:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($item->getOrderId());
$store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load(1);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load($order->getQuoteId());
$items = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection();
$quoteItem = $items->addFieldToFilter('item_id', $item->getQuoteItemId())
    ->setQuote($quote)
    ->getFirstItem();

$helper = new Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration();
foreach ($helper->getOptions($quoteItem) as $itemOption){
    $text .= '<dt>' . $itemOption['label'] . ':</dt> ';
    $text .= '<dd>' . $itemOption['print_value'] . '</dd>';
}
```

$quoteItem returns protected items:

```
object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item)#884 (24) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(16) "sales_quote_item" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(4) "item" ["_quote":protected]=> NULL ["_options":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_optionsByCode":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_notRepresentOptions":protected]=> array(1)
```

How the best way to make this foreach?

Comment: depends on your server configuration - check php/apache/nginx error logs

Comment: Can you explain a little more where you are doing this code?